# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : HTTPS endpoint not secure

Tags: c#, https, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0, self-hosting

I'm running an ASP.NET Core 6 self-hosted application project that contains some controllers and everything works fine on my dev machine.
The goal is to use this application in a local network server and some local computers will have a client application (wpf) that will call this application controllers.

After I've developed and tested everything on my dev machine, I've started using this dev machine as a local server and try to access it from other clients so instead calling my endpoint `localhost:8080`. I start calling "172.24.242.181:8080" everything works but I get a "NOT SECURE" error from the browser and I don't know how to fix that.

I realized if I call endpoint different than "localhost:8080" I always get the "NOT SECURE" issue.

I believe is something related with certificates but I don't have any know-how and I would like your support to guide me to do the right thing :)

[Description-Image-Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH9QR.png)

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using ProjectX.Api;
using ProjectX.Services.Api;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

//to run as service
var options = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
};

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);

#region Certificate

/*
// Use the certificate to start the web app
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenAnyIP(8080, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps(@"c:\temp\emacon.pfx", "abc");
    });
});
*/

#endregion

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();

//RunTimeServerInstance (24/7 service)
builder.Services.AddHostedService<RunTimeServerInstanceHostService>();

//UserService (for api auhentication)
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();

//Authentication Bearer (for api auhentication)
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer   = JWT.Issuer,
            ValidAudience = JWT.Audience,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JWT.Key))
        };
    });


// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


//avoid json serialize camel casing
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opts => 
{ 
    opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    opts.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals; //para aceitar NAN, infinitos etc no json
});


//Nedeed
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
});


//run as service
builder.Host.UseWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = "ProjectX Api Service";
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

//Api authentication
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

//app.Run();
await app.RunAsync();
```

I did some web research in try to add a self signed certificate but the problems keeps.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is the self-signed certificate is not trusted for your computer.

If you want to let all the computer inside your company local network trust the certificate, you should let your AD domain server to sign a certificate which could be trusted for all the computer inside your company local network.

Then you use this certificate inside this asp.net core application, then this issue will be solved.